# Prevent a method to be called multiple times in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to experiment with reactjs multiple fields component by implementing [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) but unable to figure out why method in the children called multiple times here.

```js
var i = 0;
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(key) {
    //this method is called multiple times during Render()
    console.log(i++);
    return function(e) {
      var value = key !== 'inStockOnly' ? e.target.value : e.target.checked;
      this.props.onUserInput(
        key,
        value
      );
    }.bind(this);
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="search" value={this.props.filterText} placeholder="Search ..." ref={(input) => {input.focus();}} onChange={this.handleChange('filterText')} />
        <p>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.inStockOnly} onChange={this.handleChange('inStockOnly')} />
        {' '}
        Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class FilterableProducts extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    filterText: '',
    inStockOnly: false
  };
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}
handleInput(key, value) {
/*var state = {};
  state[key] = value;  
  console.log(state);
  this.setState(state);*/

  //above is what I am trying to do later on but still stuck on why setState does not work
  //test
  this.setState({
    filterText: 'foo',
    inStockOnly: true
  });
}
  render() {
    return (      
      <SearchBar filterText={this.state.filterText} inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly} onUserInput={this.handleInput} />            
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**

```js
//updated handleChanged
handleChange(key, e) {
      var value = key !== 'inStockOnly' ? e.target.value : e.target.checked;
      this.props.onUserInput(
        key,
        value
      );
}

//updated handleInput
handleInput(key, value) {
  //var state = {};
  //state[key] = value;
  //this.setState(state);
  //console.log(state);
  //above is what I am trying to do
  //test
  this.setState({
    filterText: 'g',
    inStockOnly: true
  });
}
```

```html
<!--i changed the event listener to this
  now its not called directly
-->
<input type="search" value={this.props.filterText} placeholder="Search ..." ref={(input) => {input.focus();}} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange('filterText', e)} />
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: See my edit. Also your function should be getting called. It will only be called when the input changes now instead of once on render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: That's correct, they are supposed to be called immediately because you are returning a function which binds to the `onChange` for when it fires. The inner function will only be called `onChange`. You will need to pass the key in though.

**Second Edit**:

```
handleInput(event) {
  this.setState({
    filterText: event.target.value,
    inStockOnly: true
  });
}
<input type="search" value={this.state.filterText} placeholder="Search ..." ref={(input) => {input.focus();}} onChange={this.handleInput} />
```

**Original**:

```
handleChange(key) {
    //this method is called multiple times during Render()
    console.log(i++);
    return function(key, event) {
      var value = key !== 'inStockOnly' ? event.target.value : event.target.checked;
      this.props.onUserInput(
        key,
        value
      );
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Event will be passed as the last parameter when it fires.

What isn't working about the `setState`? You are using it correctly in `handleInput`.

The commented out `setState` won't work though. You should only create state in the constructor and also do note though that the `console.log()` after you set the state may still be empty though because `setState` is asynchronous for performance and may not be updated until later.

```
var state = {};
state[key] = value;  
console.log(state);
this.setState(state);*/
```

You will want `componentDidUpdate` instead and perform the console.log in there or use the callback of `setState`, i.e `this.setState({state[key]: value}, function() {console.log(this.state)});` which will always give the correct state.

Comment: thank you so much, that is answering the question. BUt i am still could not make my setState works. Last tried when i remove the `return function()..` the `handleInput()` did not get called

Comment: @RizkiDPrast are you talking about the `handleInput` or `handleChange` function? I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @RizkiDPrast Actually returning the function from `handleChange` should still work, but the inner function will only be called `onChange` so what you were doing is correct, the functions are supposed to get called immediately because they return a function that gets binded to the `onChange`

Comment: ya it gets called sorry. but please see the updated question above, could you help me further please? with current code, every time i type in, the SearchBar always updated to '' (empty) instead of 'g'

Comment: @RizkiDPrast see my edit. Oops forgot inputs don't render anything in them. You are using `this.props.filterText` instead of `this.state.filterText`

Comment: @RizkiDPrast It's pointless using `this.state.filterText` in the search tag though because you are just setting it to the exact same thing each time due to the `setState` in `handleInput`. Not sure what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinMazzaDawson
It turns out the `ref` attribute is the culprit. I removed it and It works
regards

Answer (score 0):

just found out why my 'setState' "Not working". It is the because of unproper use of the `ref` attribute. By removing `ref={(input) => {input.focus();}}`, the code will works. And in my case I can change it to `ref={(input) => if(input === null) return; {input.focus();}}` will keep the focus function. It is because `ref` function is called twice: `whenMount` and `didMount`

so fully functional method will be:

```js
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(key, e) {
      var value = key !== 'inStockOnly' ? e.target.value : e.target.checked;
      this.props.onUserInput(
        key,
        value
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="search" value={this.props.filterText} placeholder="Search ..." ref={(input) => {if(input === null) return;input.focus();}} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange('filterText', e)} />
        <p>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.inStockOnly} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange('inStockOnly', e)} />
        {' '}
        Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class FilterableProducts extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    filterText: '',
    inStockOnly: false
  };
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}
handleInput(key, value) {
  var state = {};
  state[key] = value;
  this.setState(state);
}
  render() {
    return (      
      <SearchBar filterText={this.state.filterText} inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly} onUserInput={this.handleInput} />      
    );
  }
}
```

by using `onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange('inStockOnly', e)} />` and `onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange('filterText', e)}` we can avoid using to much `ref` in multiple fields Component